# Restircting specific app features in an app after free trial is completed

Tags: android, ios, mobile

We want to implement the following pricing model for an app in app store and play store.

App users gets 'x' months of free trial. Post trial app user cannot access a particular feature in the app, unless they subscribe to the yearly fee 'y'. They can access other features of the app.

Is this possible?
if not, what is the closest that can be done?

Comment: Never used them before, but you should be able to achieve them by using the Google Play Billing API. Have a look at them here, where you can find detailed information about how to set a free trial https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#trials

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible.

If you publish your app in google play store, you can use in-app purchase and set up item on google play console. I don't know about apple store, but I think it's the same.

If you want to implement that independent with google play store or app store. I think you should implement on the server side, or you can try Firebase & Firebase App Config for your app.

I'm not trying that before, but I think Firebase can solve your problem in simple way.